# <input type="search"> no longer shows cancel button (x) under iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, forms, input

```
<input type="search">
```

All online articles indicate that and `input` with `type=search` will have a clear button on the right side of the input (on Apple products).

This still works in Safari on MacOS, but in mobile safari (iOS9) this no longer works.

**Is there a way to get this search-cancel-button back?**

I already tried this:

```
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:searchfield-cancel-button;}
```

I also tried giving the input a `name` and `value`. Also putting it inside a `form`, but to no avail.

I found a [page that added the button using css](http://davidbcalhoun.com/a/webkit-search-cancel-button.html), but on my iPhone, pressing the button will place the carret inside the button, which is super weird, and unusable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So let me start with how I got to where I am. First I loaded an input as `type="search"` in OS X and iOS 9. I saw as you did that it worked on OS X but not iOS. So I started investigating. When I looked under accessibility with no text in the input it only had a single child element. When I typed in text it suddenly had two.

[image]

See in the bottom corner under accessibility. When I hover over `div:role(button)` it highlights the little clear X as you can see above. So then I tested the same thing in iOS and it does indeed do the same thing only when you hover over the same element it doesn't highlight anything. So it is being added by safari in iOS.

Next I started playing with some CSS. My first thought was if its not showing maybe its just a display issue and so I added this.

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
}
```

Which now got me this in iOS:

[image]

So it is there but for some reason on iOS its hidden and not getting any content. Also clicking it is not clearing the search field either once you force it to be visible. I am still messing around with it but right now it seems like they broke it. Intentionally or not I am unsure. For the time being a CSS and JavaScript solution may get you back to where you want to be faster. I will update answer if I find anything else.

**EDIT**

This is driving me nuts. I searched all their developer documentation for safari and iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/(null)-SW1

They still reference it as being supported in above link but those documents have not been updated since 2012 if you look at the revision history and I can't find any newer ones. Blarg. I have tried every combination I can but it just doesn't work. I think its safe to assume, since it shouldn't be this hard to make it work, that they broke or removed it and don't feel it was important enough to mention. Their documentation says to use something like this CSS:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
}

*::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

At this point like I said roll your own or maybe even file a bug report and maybe we can find out for sure.

### Bug reports submitted to Apple:

- [AtheistP3ace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240676/atheistp3ace) submitted a bug report to Apple, bug number 24932348.
- [Splaktar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633107/splaktar) spoke to Apple developers and they responded and said that there does appear to be a regression since iOS 9. Issue ID 35131989, which was eventually closed for inactivity, and then marked as a duplicate of AtheistP3ace's bug report.

Comment: Great research. Guess I can add this one to my list of stuff that no longer works on iOS. Using JS and CSS, (and disabling this feature on chrome) would be a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks! Yea its really odd that there is absolutely no mention from apple anywhere that I can find of removing this. I am still playing around with different setups to see if I can get it to work. I will update question if I find anything else.

Comment: Still can't get it working but did a bit more searching so updated my answer.

Comment: I also submitted a bug report to apple. Lets see what they say.

Comment: That should be interesting. Thank you for all your work. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the research. I still want the cancel button for Chrome users though; probably got to use some Javascript.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Do you still have a link to the report?

Comment: @Andrei What do you mean? The link to the bug report I filed?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace yeah :)

Comment: @Andrei hmm I entered the bug through my developer account. I can't see a way to share a link to it. Unfortunately there has been zero movement on it at all. Apple doesn't seem to care.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace do you have a bug number? I just spoke to some Safari devs and they wanted an Apple bug to reference. Thank you.

Comment: @Splaktar The bug number is: 24932348

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Thank you. They are investigating this now and told me that it appears to be a regression due to a fix in iOS 9. I also opened issue ID 35131989 for this. They asked me for an estimated number of customers impacted by this and I let them know that it is about every Enterprise iOS user in the world :)

Comment: @Splaktar Awesome! Would love to see this issue resolved! Thanks for moving it forward a bit more.

Comment: @Splaktar did you ever get anything more from Apple on this?

Comment: I must to add !important for some reason: 
-webkit-appearance: searchfield !important;

Comment: @lars-c-magnusson no, they asked me to give them a "sysdiagnose" which was not something that I was familiar with. I also didn't have an iOS device to use for this. They closed the bug after I did not provide the "sysdiagnose".

Comment: This is still a problem in iOS 12.1. I created a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Splaktar/pen/VqrmGr) reproduction. I looked into "sysdiagnose" some more, but it doesn't seem possible to do in a simulator.

Comment: I finally figured out [how to do a "sysdiagnose" on an iOS Simulator](https://github.com/jessesquires/jessesquires.com/issues/87#issuecomment-450595104) and I added that to my bug report. I also pinged a couple people at Apple who can hopefully revive the closed issue.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I finally got them to re-open and look at my bug. They have marked it a duplicate of your bug (24932348) but otherwise don't have any updates. I can't see your bug due to their closed system. Have you seen any progress there?

Comment: @Splaktar no there has been zero movement on mine since day one. Glad to hear you made progress!! If you have time and care to share update with anything new. I’m always interested to hear.

Comment: Thank you for your including your research!

Comment: @JoshBuchea no problem! happy to help.

Comment: Still the same issue in 2022, but a work around from the blue box is just to change the background so it is an SVG of a cross. Works in Chrome...

Answer (score 32):

I was able to get it working on iphone using the below css

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {

  /* Remove default */
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  /* Now your own custom styles */
   height: 14px;
   width: 14px;
   display: block;
   background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAAn0lEQVR42u3UMQrDMBBEUZ9WfQqDmm22EaTyjRMHAlM5K+Y7lb0wnUZPIKHlnutOa+25Z4D++MRBX98MD1V/trSppLKHqj9TTBWKcoUqffbUcbBBEhTjBOV4ja4l4OIAZThEOV6jHO8ARXD+gPPvKMABinGOrnu6gTNUawrcQKNCAQ7QeTxORzle3+sDfjJpPCqhJh7GixZq4rHcc9l5A9qZ+WeBhgEuAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  /* setup all the background tweaks for our custom icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* icon size */
  background-size: 14px;

}
```

```html
<input type="search" value="Example">
```

Comment: Well, it does show a custom button, but it's still ineffective for me. Did you find a way to actually clear the field contents with this button?

Comment: did you add <input type="search"> for the input component you are trying to get the button with?

Comment: This works on iOS 14 at the time of this comment, including the clearing UX for the element `input[type="search"]`. For whatever reason the Apple team who provide this asset didn't so the control is there and visible as a little dot if you give it a border with no image and no size so it collapses. If someone wants to support Apple's software feel free to tell them, I don't think they're going to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with only `<input type="search">` in iOS 9, you'll need to do some "hacking".

Here's live [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tleon/af8s9kjb/1/) example.

Comment: Do you have any example for the same in reactjs code ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove height property, it worked for my :)

Comment: Put like this comment in comment section