# <input type=“search”> no longer shows cancel button (x) under firefox

Tags: html

I found that `<input type=“search”>` only works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.
How can I make `<input type=“search”>` show the cancel button (x) in Firefox?

Comment: Besides missing cancel button FF does not clear input on pressing Esc key.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Webkit derived browsers put in an x to clear a value. Firefox does not. However firefox supports this feature, but it does nothing about it and you need to style it your self to show the X button in firefox.

Following link will help you to achieve the goal: [`HTML Textbox with a clear button in Pure CSS and without JavaScript`](http://codepen.io/shidhincr/pen/ICLBD)

Comment: Thank you! do you know how to do it?

Comment: @ZichenMa I have added the link to my answer. Please use up vote, if it really helped you. Thank you.

Comment: thank you so so much! That's exactly what I want, but when I copy the code into a blank html page, In firefox, I need to move my mouse to a little bit left and then I can delete the content. However, it works perfect in google chrome.

Comment: @ZichenMa you may need to do some changes in CSS. It would be better if you post your code, then we can work on it. do not forget the VOTE ;-)

Comment: just want to say: thank you so so much! I have fixed this small thing! Really appreciated your answer. BTW, I am new to here, could you tell me how to VOTE?

Comment: @ZichenMa just hit the UP-ARROW at the left side of my answer.

Comment: Only one problem with this answer, it only works if it is the only input in the form. Otherwise every field gets cleared.

Comment: What about modifying an MUI Textfield type="search" to show this "X"

Comment: @ErikVeland That makes this "solution" useless for most cases. Why doesn't FireFox just provide an easy way to add the X button like other browsers? FireFox itself shows that X button if you type something in the "Find in Settings" field at the top-right corner of the Settings page?

Comment: Actually supported but not enabled by default on Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654288

Answer (score 11):

While the accepted answer is working as it can be seen in the codepen,
I feel the need to explain how this is working and what to be aware of.
As it took me quite some time to get it working as expected.

1. For anybody who was wondering how the clear is working `type="reset"` is causing this. 
   [Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset)

> elements of type reset are rendered as buttons, with a default click event handler that resets all of the inputs in the form to their initial values.

2. This brings us to the second point of what to be aware of.
   As the docs explains, the input or button of type reset will only work within a form. However, this creates a problem when having multiple inputs in a form, as all of them will be reset. 
   Another caveat would be the fact, that while fixing the clear button on firefox this will now produce multiple clear buttons in all the other browsers that do have support for it.
3. A little feature is that the css content also accepts a `url()`. This means that for instance custom svg's can be used as a clear icon.