# Hide search textbox close button on mouse over

Tags: html, css

Look this fiddle: [Click here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XKrc/1/)

Here is the code of the fiddle.

```
<input id="Search" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

After type some word in textbox and click out side the textbox , that close button is disappear, and on mouse over the textbox ,again that close button is display.

I don't want to display that close button on mouse over, that close button is display only if textbox is focus.

Anyone can help me to find the solution for this problem.

Comment: You mean hiding it on hover, showing it on focus - like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5XKrc/980/

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, let me try in my code

Comment: @CBroe , you can add answer , i will accept the answer , your solution is helpful to me

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
#Search:hover::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
  display:none;
}
#Search:focus::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
  display:block;
}
```

And it will be work.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the button in the hover state, and show it in the focus state:

```
#Search:hover::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
  display:none;
}
#Search:focus::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
  display:block;
}
```

(The latter is necessary because hover and focus can apply at the same time - so if you want it to be visible again when you are hovering over the already focused field, you need to latter rule as well.)

Comment: This is the exact same answer as another one posted half an hour prior...

Comment: @BrianH. yes it is, and if you look at the comments, that was the solution proposed by me in a fiddle. Normally I don’t mind, but since the other answer seemed to be just a complete rip-off of my suggestion, I decided to add my own answer ...