# tabulator: change / modify then header filter "clear" icon (or image)

Tags: javascript, svg, customization, tabulator

[image: cross icon]

I all,

I would like customize theme but i cannot find, modify or change the "cross" icon in the header filter (see image). This icon appear when the header filter is not null and focus done. The blue gradient is not suitable for my theme.

If you have an idea. I hope it is usefull ;)
Thanks.

I have already change svg data for the tick an cross icon/button. but the cross icon in the header filter does not appear linked with these data.

Comment: That cross icon is not part of Tabulator. This is built-in with chrome and IE for input type = “Search” which is what Tabulator uses for the header filter input boxes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804016/editing-input-type-search-pseudo-element-button-x